Problem with storing markdown in database and rendering using React-Markdown
I am having problem with storing Markdown in database and rendering using React-Markdown.
For example I have to store Markdown without any line breaks inside my DB.
# **Marc Márquez: The Maverick of MotoGP**  In the world of MotoGP, few names resonate with the same intensity and excitement as Marc Márquez. As of September 2024, Márquez remains one of the most dominant and electrifying figures in motorcycle racing. This blog delves into his journey, achievements, and what makes him a true legend of the sport.  ![Alt text](https://static.autox.com/uploads/2024/09/MotoGP-Marc-Marquez-2-.jpg)

Which actually is in following format:
# **Marc Márquez: The Maverick of MotoGP**

In the world of MotoGP, few names resonate with the same intensity and excitement as Marc Márquez. As of September 2024, Márquez remains one of the most dominant and electrifying figures in motorcycle racing. This blog delves into his journey, achievements, and what makes him a true legend of the sport.

![Alt text](https://static.autox.com/uploads/2024/09/MotoGP-Marc-Marquez-2-.jpg)

I tried several things like using \n <br/> (with rehype-raw). But none of these are able to mimic actual line break.
According to the above Markdown the heading is different from body and image but using <br> is resulting into no change and the below para is also getting converted into heading 1 (#).
I am using MySQL as a database and using Spring Boot as backend.
I have to store the Markdown in such format because I have to pass data using JSON and It doesn't support line breaks.

Not sure what your specific issue is. Also, you haven't provided any code or any database details (and the [tag:database] and [tag:json] tags don't help). Please edit to provide a [mcve]. Also, all details need to be here, in your question, not as a link to an external site.

Why do you have to store the markdown without line breaks? I hope it is not because it is concatenated directly into an SQL statement string

@cbr I am using JSON and we can't add data to DB with line breaks included. If there is a way to do so please suggest so.

JSON supports line breaks? they just get encoded as \n  when you do JSON.stringify() - JSON.stringify("hello\nworld")

@cbr When I get the data from my backend to front end. I want that "# ABC\n\nXYZ" get converted to
"#ABC
---Line Break---
XYZ
"
Is it possible?

It probably already has the line breaks - it may be just the console stringifying the line breaks as \n. If you console.log() the string, does it have the proper line breaks? If it is as JSON, aren't you doing JSON.parse()?
